# Is it fine to remove ppa source list while the application is not removed?

Tags: apt, ppa

Ok, I just installed **Pinta** from launchpad. After the installation finished I decided to remove the ppa source lists. I run the application just fine, **Pinta** fire-up flawlessly.

I do this for any other applications that I'd installed from launchpad. 
Any suggestion?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> Is it fine to remove ppa source list while the application is not removed?

If the application gets an update you won't get it automatically (or at least not when you do `sudo apt-get upgrade`) so in most of cases, no, is not fine, since you will not receive updates and security fixes, bug fixes, etc. You can do it, but is **on your own risk.**

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is fine , only thing will happen on running update manager that application will not recive any updates.